# Unable to fetch data from txt file. "XMLhttpRequest error"

Tags: ajax

Please let me know why I am getting error while fetching the data from "hello.txt" file. My "index.html" and "hello.txt" file both are in the same directory. The error is mentioned Here:- [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUp2n.png)

```
//index.html file
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Ajax Tutorial Practice</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="button"> Click Me to Get the Data </button>
    <script>
         let button=document.getElementById("button");
         button.addEventListener("click",function()
         {
            console.log("hello");
            //xhr Object
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            
            //Opening the connection
            xhr.open('GET', 'hello.txt', true);

            // onload method 
            xhr.onload=function()
            {
                if(this.status===200)
                {
                    console.log(this.responseText);
                }
            }
            //sending the request
            xhr.send();
         })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't fetch file urls (i.e. `file://*`) that violates Cross Origin Policy. Just host your files through http the same code will work fine. You can use apache or node `http-server` module to do that. You can follow this [blog] (https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/06/22/nodejs-setup-simple-http-server-local-web-server).

Comment: Thanks brother for your help. My code works now.